# Join tables with unknown number of rows without repeating column that is joined by

Tags: sql, join, primary-key

Here's my quandary:

I need to join all columns of two tables based on a primary key, but I don't want to repeat the primary key in the results.
The second table has the primary key and then unknown number and names of columns.

So essentially I want

```
SELECT * (except for b.PK) FROM 
  TableA a
    JOIN TableB b ON a.PK = b.PK
```

The obvious solution would be to select all columns explicitly from table a except for a.PK, but let's say that I don't know the number or names of columns in table a either (except I know it has the PK).

So to sum:

**How do I join two tables by their PKs, where I don't know the rest of their columns explicitly, and without repeating the PK in the results?**

EDIT: (Using T-SQL with SQL Server)

Comment: What SQL product is this?

Comment: SQL Server - using T-SQL... sorry for not specifying

Answer (score 2):

Something like `SELECT * except column foo FROM ...` doesn't exist. But you can use a natural join, which eliminates redundant columns. You haven't mentioned your RDBMS, so here's an [explanation from the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html). A natural join is standard SQL though.

> The columns of a NATURAL join or a USING join may be different from
>   previously. Specifically, redundant output columns no longer appear,
>   and the order of columns for SELECT * expansion may be different from
>   before.
>
> Consider this set of statements:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (i INT, j INT);
CREATE TABLE t2 (k INT, j INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,1);
SELECT * FROM t1 NATURAL JOIN t2;
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (j);
```

> Previously, the statements produced this output:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| i    | j    | k    | j    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+------+
+------+------+------+------+
| i    | j    | k    | j    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

> In the first SELECT statement, column j appears in both tables and
>   thus becomes a join column, so, according to standard SQL, it should
>   appear only once in the output, not twice. Similarly, in the second
>   SELECT statement, column j is named in the USING clause and should
>   appear only once in the output, not twice. But in both cases, the
>   redundant column is not eliminated. Also, the order of the columns is
>   not correct according to standard SQL.
>
> Now the statements produce this output:

```
+------+------+------+
| j    | i    | k    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
+------+------+------+
| j    | i    | k    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
```

> The redundant column is eliminated and the column order is correct
>   according to standard SQL

Comment: Interesting - I never knew about Natural Joins... unfortunately, it appears that SQL Server [does not support natural joins](http://database.blogs.webucator.com/2010/03/31/why-sql-server-doesnt-support-natural-join-syntax/), but considers an INNER join to be the same thing... which in my case is not true, as inner join does not eliminate duplicate columns